# adding additional buttons to nested data table in R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

Is there a way to add additional action buttons to both parent and child rows in a nested data table? I've tried adding the buttons via JS and the Shiny side, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Most of the code was borrowed from this post: [Matching Parent/Child data up in a DataTable in R Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838658/matching-parent-child-data-up-in-a-datatable-in-r-shiny-app) Thanks

```
    library(data.table)
    library(DT)
    library(purrr)
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(foreach)
    library(data.table)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    df <- data.frame("Gene.5" = c("PDE1A", "SLC45A3", "SLC45A3", "SLC45A3", "TARBP1", "CUL4A", "CUL4A"),
                     "Junction.5" = c("chr2:182198385:-", "chr1:205680393:-", "chr1:205680393:-", "chr1:205680393:-", "chr1:234420701:-", "chr13:113245060:+", "chr13:113245060:+"),
                     "Gene.3" = c("ELK4", "ETV2", "ETV2", "ETV2", "CEACAM1", "chr13_q32.3", "chr13_q32.3"),
                     "Junction.3" = c("chr1:205623892:-", "chr19:35642433:+", "chr19:35642614:+", "chr19:35642964:+", "chr19:42522203:-", "chr13:100068494:-", "chr13:100069868:-"),
                     "breakpoints" = c("1", "5", "5", "5", "2", "3", "3"),
                     "primary" = c("p","p","s","s","p","p","s")
    )
    head(df)
    gene_list <- c("SLC45A3", "CUL4A")
    
    df$V4=(
        df$Gene.5 %in% gene_list |
            df$Gene.3 %in% gene_list
    )
    print(df)
    par <- subset(df, df$primary == 'p')
    ch <- df
    
    all <-rbind(par,ch) #rbind the columns
    ch_only_df <- all[!duplicated(all,fromLast = FALSE)&!duplicated(all,fromLast = TRUE),] 
    print(ch_only_df)
    children_list<-list()
    for (row in 1:nrow(par)) {
        g5 <- paste(par[row, "Gene.5"])
        print(g5)
        g3 <- paste(par[row, "Gene.3"])
        tdf <- subset(ch_only_df, ch_only_df$Gene.5 == g5 & ch_only_df$Gene.3 == g3)
        if (nrow(tdf)<1){
            children_list[[row]] <- data.frame(NULL)
        }else{
            children_list[[row]] <- tdf
        }
    }
    children_list
    NestedData <- function(dat, children){
        stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
        g <- function(d){
            if(is.data.frame(d)){
                purrr::transpose(d)
            }else{
                purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
            }
        }
        subdats <- lapply(children, g)
        oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
        cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }
    
    rowNames <- FALSE
    colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
    
   
    ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
        titlePanel("Example"),
        checkboxInput("unroll", label = "Panel Genes", value = FALSE),
        tags$hr(),
        mainPanel(DTOutput("my_table"))
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
       
        market_mix_table <- reactive({
            Dat <- NestedData(
                dat = par,
                children = children_list
            )
            if (!input$unroll) {
                Dat
            } else {
                Dat <- subset(Dat, Dat$V4 == TRUE)
            }
            return(Dat)
        })
 ## make the callback
    parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
    callback = JS(
        sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
        sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
        "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
        "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
        "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
        "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
        "  }else{",
        "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
        "  }",
        "}",
        "",
        "// make the table header of the nested table",
        "var format = function(d, childId){",
        "  if(d != null){",
        "    var html = ", 
        "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
        "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
        "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
        "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
        "    }",
        "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
        "    return html;",
        "  } else {",
        "    return '';",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
        "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
        "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
        "    $(row).css('background-color', '##DDDDDD');",
        "    $(row).hover(function(){",
        "     $(this).css('background-color', '#DDDDDD');",
        "    }, function() {",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', '##DDDDDD');",
        "    });",
        "  } else {",
        "    $(row).css('background-color', '#EAF2F8');",
        "    $(row).hover(function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDDDDD');",
        "    }, function() {",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', '#EAF2F8');",
        "    });",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
        "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
        "  $('th', thead).css({",
        "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
        "    'color': '#00274c',",
        "    'background-color': '##DDDDDD'",
        "  });",
        "};",
        "",
        "// make the datatable",
        "var format_datatable = function(d, childId){",
        "  var dataset = [];",
        "  var n = d.length - 1;",
        "  for(var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++){",
        "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
        "      return [value];",
        "    });",
        "    dataset.push(datarow);",
        "  }",
        "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
        "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
        "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
        "                 'data': dataset,",
        "                 'autoWidth': true,",
        "                 'deferRender': true,",
        "                 'info': false,",
        "                 'lengthChange': false,",
        "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
        "                 'order': [],",
        "                 'paging': false,",
        "                 'scrollX': false,",
        "                 'scrollY': false,",
        "                 'searching': false,",
        "                 'sortClasses': false,",
        "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
        "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
        "                 'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
        "               });",
        "  } else {",
        "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
        "            'data': dataset,",
        "            'autoWidth': true,",
        "            'deferRender': true,",
        "            'info': false,",
        "            'lengthChange': false,",
        "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
        "            'order': [],",
        "            'paging': false,",
        "            'scrollX': false,",
        "            'scrollY': false,",
        "            'searching': false,",
        "            'sortClasses': false,",
        "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
        "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
        "            'columnDefs': [", 
        "              {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
        "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
        "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
        "             ]",
        "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// display the child table on click",
        "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
        "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
        "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
        "      td = $(this),",
        "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
        "      rowIdx = row.index();",
        "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
        "    row.child.hide();",
        "    td.html('&oplus;');",
        "  } else {",
        "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
        "    row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
        "    td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
        "    format_datatable(row.data(), childId);",
        "  }",
        "});")
    
        output$my_table <- DT::renderDT({
            Dat <- market_mix_table()
            datatable(
                Dat, callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
                options = list(
                               columnDefs = list(
                                   list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
                                   list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx)
                                   
                               )
                )
            )
        })
    }
    
    # Run the application
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is the difficulty? You just have to put `as.character(actionButton(......` in the cells you want.

Comment: Do you know of an example I can refer to? also, does escape = FALSE for this to work? I've tried this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739303/r-shiny-handle-action-buttons-in-data-table thanks

Comment: Error in which(Dat[, 1] != "") : object 'Dat' not found

Comment: Moreover there are unnecessary library() calls in your code. Please remove them.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it can't find Dat in `which(Dat[,1]!= "")` for some reason. It worked earlier.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat0   = iris[1:3,]        # main table, with three rows
dat01  = airquality[1:4,]  # |- child of first row
dat02  = cars[1:2,]        # |- child of second row, with two rows
dat021 = mtcars[1:3,]      # |  |- child of first row of dat02
dat022 = PlantGrowth[1:4,] # |  |- child of second row of dat02
dat03  = data.frame(NULL)  # |- third row has no child

# add buttons
dat01 <- cbind(
  dat01, 
  "Click me" = as.character(htmltools::tags$button("Click me")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

Dat <- NestedData(
  dat = dat0, 
  children = list(
    dat01, 
    list(  
      dat02, 
      children = list(
        dat021, 
        dat022
      )
    ), 
    dat03 
  )
)
```

[image]